# Plane of contact of sphere

Tags: analytic-geometry, spheres

A plane of contact of sphere is locus of points of contact of all the tangent planes through a given point. I cannot visualize this. Please provide a 3D image illustrating the plane of contact of sphere

Comment: Can you visualize the two-dimensional analogue, the chord of contact of tangents to a circle through an external point? Rotate that to create surfaces.

Comment: can you give me the equation of the plane of contact for general equation of sphere with centre(-u,-v,-w) and constant d through external point (a,b,c)? I am getting the locus as a sphere again i.e. (a-x)(x+u)+(b-y)(y+v)+(c-z)(z+w)=0

Comment: Think of a ball sitting in a cone and where the points of contact are.

Comment: Mark Bennet, What is the equation of that plane?

Comment: The plane is perpendicular to the line joining the sphere center and external point. Find *any* of the tangent planes and its point of contact and you can then use the point-normal form of plane equation to construct it yourself. If you’re having specific problems solving this, update your question with the work you’ve done so that someone can help you find your error or get you unstuck.

Comment: thanks amd, but what does this sphere (a-x)(x+u)+(b-y)(y+v)+(c-z)(z+w)=0 represent?

Answer (score 0):

Let $O$ be a center of the sphere and $A$ be the given point on the sphere.

Let $K$ be a point in the space such that $AK\perp OA$.

Thus, $KA$ is a tangent line to the sphere and the set of all these points with $\{A\}$  gives a tangent plane to the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.

If $P$ is a given external point, and the tangent plane through $P$ touches the given sphere at $T$, then $T$ belongs to the sphere of diameter $PO$, where $O$ is the center of the given sphere.

The locus you want is then the intersection between those two spheres.

Answer (score 0):

Let your sphere be described by

$ p^T p = R^2 $

where $p = [x, y, z]^T$ and $R$ is the radius of the sphere.  And let there be point $P_0$ outside the sphere, and let $q$ be a point of tangency, then this means that

$ (q - P_0)^T q = 0 $

Expanding the above expression yields

$ q^T q - P_0^T q = 0 $

But $q^T q = R^2 $, therefore,

$ P_0^T q = R^2 $

and this an equation of a plane whose normal vector is along the vector $P_0$

and **passes** through the point $Q_0 = R^2 \dfrac{P_0}{\| P_0 \|^2 } $

This is the plane of contact, and is shown in the following Geogebra [worksheet](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/ypzq5udc) in blue.